# Just execute the controller without showing the lightning component window

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a quick action component labelled Login that opens a new website. The problem is when the button is clicked a small white lightning component window is also show.
Can i just open the website without showing the component window?
[image]

Here is my component code

```
<aura:component controller="PwdMgmtLoginController" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getLoginUrls}" />

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The best that we have right now is to immediately close the dialog with [force:closeQuickAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_closeQuickAction.htm). There will still be something like a half-second period of time where the modal will be visible, however.

```
({
    getLoginUrls: function(component, event, helper) {
      $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
      // Do rest of logic here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you sir, force:closeQuickAction does 99% of the work.